# How to calculate unbalanced weights for BCEWithLogitsLoss in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, multilabel-classification

I am trying to solve one multilabel problem with `270` labels and i have converted target labels into one hot encoded form. I am using `BCEWithLogitsLoss()`. Since training data is unbalanced, I am using `pos_weight` argument but i am bit confused.

`pos_weight` (Tensor, optional) – a weight of positive examples. Must be a vector with length equal to the number of classes.

Do i need to give total count of positive values of each label as a tensor or they mean something else by weights?

Comment: You can check the discussion here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dealing-with-imbalanced-datasets-in-pytorch/22596/21

Answer (score 16):

The PyTorch [documentation for BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) recommends the pos_weight to be a ratio between the negative counts and the positive counts for each class.

So, if `len(dataset)` is 1000, element 0 of your multihot encoding has 100 positive counts, then element 0 of the `pos_weights_vector` should be `900/100 = 9`. That means that the binary crossent loss will behave as if the dataset contains 900 positive examples instead of 100.

Here is my implementation:

(new, based on [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weights-in-bcewithlogitsloss/27452/21?u=crypdick))

`pos_weight = (y==0.).sum()/y.sum()`

(original)

```
  def calculate_pos_weights(class_counts):
    pos_weights = np.ones_like(class_counts)
    neg_counts = [len(data)-pos_count for pos_count in class_counts]
    for cdx, pos_count, neg_count in enumerate(zip(class_counts,  neg_counts)):
      pos_weights[cdx] = neg_count / (pos_count + 1e-5)

    return torch.as_tensor(pos_weights, dtype=torch.float)
```

Where `class_counts` is just a column-wise sum of the positive samples. I [posted it](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weights-in-bcewithlogitsloss/27452/12?u=crypdick) on the PyTorch forum and one of the PyTorch devs gave it his blessing.

Comment: Can you clear about the weights in the return? Is it pos_weights or any other weights. If it is something different could you provide more details on it?

Comment: @PaladiN sorry, my variables weren't clear. I clarified the variable names in my answer.

Comment: Another way to do the same: Get class_counts from data labels (example labels: [[0],[0],[1]...]) `classes, class_counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)`. Calculate weight: `weight = [(class_counts.sum() - x)/ (x+1e-5) for i, x in enumerate(class_counts)]`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe is a little late, but here is how I calculate the same. Looking into the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html):

> For example, if a dataset contains 100 positive and 300 negative examples of a single class, then pos_weight for the class should be equal to 300/100 = 3.

So an easy way to calcule the positive weight is using the tensor methods with your label vector "y", in my case `train_dataset.data.y`. And then calculating the total negative labels.

```
num_positives = torch.sum(train_dataset.data.y, dim=0)
num_negatives = len(train_dataset.data.y) - num_positives
pos_weight  = num_negatives / num_positives
```

Then the weights can be used easily as:

```
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight = pos_weight)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PyTorch solution

Well, actually I have gone through docs and you can simply use `pos_weight` indeed.

This argument gives weight to positive sample for each class, hence if you have `270` classes you should pass `torch.Tensor` with shape `(270,)` defining weight for each class.

Here is marginally modified snippet from [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss):

```
# 270 classes, batch size = 64    
target = torch.ones([64, 270], dtype=torch.float32)  
# Logits outputted from your network, no activation
output = torch.full([64, 270], 0.9)
# Weights, each being equal to one. You can input your own here.
pos_weight = torch.ones([270])
criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(pos_weight=pos_weight)
criterion(output, target)  # -log(sigmoid(0.9))
```

## Self-made solution

When it comes to weighting, there is no built-in solution, but you may code one yourself really easily:

```
import torch

class WeightedMultilabel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weights: torch.Tensor):
        self.loss = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        self.weights = weights.unsqueeze()

    def forward(outputs, targets):
        return self.loss(outputs, targets) * self.weights
```

`Tensor` has to be of the same length as the number of classes in your multilabel classification (270), each giving weight for your specific example.

### Calculating weights

You just add labels of every sample in your dataset, divide by the  minimum value and inverse at the end.

Sort of snippet:

```
weights = torch.zeros_like(dataset[0])
for element in dataset:
    weights += element

weights = 1 / (weights / torch.min(weights))
```

Using this approach class occurring the least will give normal loss, while others will have weights smaller than `1`.

It might cause some instability during training though, so you might want to experiment with those values a little (maybe `log` transform instead of linear?)

## Other approach

You may think about upsampling/downsampling (though this operation is complicated as you would add/delete other classes as well, so advanced heuristics would be needed I think).

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a quick revision on @crypdick's answer, this implementation of the function worked for me:

```
def calculate_pos_weights(class_counts,data):
    pos_weights = np.ones_like(class_counts)
    neg_counts = [len(data)-pos_count for pos_count in class_counts]
    for cdx, (pos_count, neg_count) in enumerate(zip(class_counts,  neg_counts)):
        pos_weights[cdx] = neg_count / (pos_count + 1e-5)

    return torch.as_tensor(pos_weights, dtype=torch.float)
```

Where `data` is the dataset you're trying to apply weights to.